# MySQL : How to convert multiple row to single row? in mysql

Tags: mysql, pivot

I want to convert multiple rows to a single row, based on week. It should look like the following. Can any one help me?

```
id      |   Weight   |  Created   |
 1      |    120     | 02-04-2012 |
 2      |    110     | 09-04-2012 |
 1      |    100     | 16-04-2012 |
 1      |    130     | 23-04-2012 |
 2      |    140     | 30-04-2012 |
 3      |    150     | 07-05-2012 |
```

Result should look like this:

```
id      |   Weight_week1  | Weight_week2  |  weight_week3  | weight_week4  |
 1      |     120         |     100       |      130       |               |
 2      |     110         |     140       |                |               |
 3      |     150         |               |                |               |
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How to define `Week 1`, `Week 2` and so on ?

Comment: one query cannot complete your wish. You have to use multiple queries for your task.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MYSQL - Rows to Columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
SELECT
    t.id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN WeekNbr=1 THEN Table1.Weight ELSE 0 END) AS Weight_week1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN WeekNbr=2 THEN Table1.Weight ELSE 0 END) AS Weight_week2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN WeekNbr=3 THEN Table1.Weight ELSE 0 END) AS Weight_week3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN WeekNbr=4 THEN Table1.Weight ELSE 0 END) AS Weight_week4
FROM
    (
    SELECT  
        (
           WEEK(Created, 5) - 
           WEEK(DATE_SUB(Created, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(Created) - 1 DAY), 5) + 1 
        )as WeekNbr,
        Table1.id,
        Table1.Weight,
        Table1.Created
    FROM
        Table1
    ) AS t
GROUP BY
    t.id
```

I don't know if you want a `AVG`,`SUM`,`MAX` or `MIN` but you can change the aggregate to what you want.

Useful references:

- [Function for week of the month in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785206/function-for-week-of-the-month-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

if this a single table then

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(weight) as Weight,
        WEEK(Created) as Week
Group by Week(Created)
```

This will give you a row each having week id and comma seperated whights

Answer (score 0):

you cannot create fields on the fly like that but you can group them.

use `GROUP_CONCAT` to deliver results with a delimiter that you can separate on later.

Comment: Maybe the OP wants some other form of aggregation?  SUM?  AVG?  Question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this:

```
SELECT id, created, weight, (
    SELECT MIN( created ) FROM weights WHERE w.id = weights.id
) AS `min` , round( DATEDIFF( created, (
   SELECT MIN( created )
FROM weights
WHERE w.id = weights.id ) ) /7) AS diff
FROM weights AS w
ORDER BY id, diff
```

This code does not do pivot table. You should add some additional code to convert the data to your needs. You may run into trouble if you use WEEK() because of the years.