# Challenging MySQL query for html/PHP report

Tags: php, html, mysql

Here's a challenge for a good MySQL coder.
We would greatly appreciate some help on a query to create a MySQL report displayed in an html/PHP page.

We know how to collect the data and store it, and have the PHP report layout, but are lost as to how to structure the query.

We have two MySQL tables – "visitors" and "buyers".

1. Visitors table – for visitors to our website coming in through a
   particular URL which identifies the sales_rep and one of many
   marketing  codes they create themselves.
2. Buyers table – for those who buy something.

A visitor may visit our website through the following link, for example:

```
www.sales_rep.website.com/index.php?marketing=code1/code2/code3
```

In the "visitors" table we include three fields:

- sales_rep
- date
- marketing_CODE – (which in this case would be the "code1/code2/code3" in a string, but each sales_rep could have several marketing_CODES based on their advertising activities; such as "code1a/codeTX/codeM2" and "market-z/ad-123")

When a visitor buys something, we add them to a "buyers" table, which includes:

- sales_rep
- date
- marketing_TYPE – (which can be "URL", "referral", or some other type)
- marketing_VALUE – (which will the marketing_CODE if the marketing_TYPE is URL)

We need to see a report for each specific sales rep, for any specified month, sorted by marketing code, only for marketing_TYPE == "URL".

This report needs to show a week-by-week breakdown of visitors and buyers activities for each marketing_CODE, as follows:

[image: Table Example]

To ensure clarity, in the above table, in WEEK 1, 8 Visitors came into the website through a link with "code1/code2/", and 5 of them purchased something.

We've attempted to begin our query with the following, but don't know where to go with it:

1. `$chosen_month = $_POST['chosen_month'];`
2. `SELECT * FROM visitors INNER JOIN buyers ON sales_rep WHERE marketing_type = "URL" AND sales_rep = '$sales_rep' AND date('Y-m') = $'chosen_month' ;`
3. Using a while statement, we would generate the table cells for each of the records found.  Using this, we know how to list every record, but we can't figure out how display non-distinct records once, display their count, then display distinct records.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Whatever you're doing here, it would benefit from some [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). Injecting `$_POST` values directly into your query is a **VERY BAD IDEA**.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I am just beginning to learn about protecting against sql injection.  When the variables are actually created in PHP, we will use the mysql_real_escape_string function to protect the data.  The post comes from a drop-down menu, so this should be enough to secure it, right?

Comment: You must use `mysql_real_escape_string` on any and all values, though. It can be a challenge to ensure you've got every single one, which is why using [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) instead of the deprecated `mysql_query` interface. Be sure to test your app with a [SQL injection testing tool](http://sqlmap.org/) to be sure you're not totally exposed.

Comment: Thanks again.  I will definitely read up on PDO.  Most of our code has been written using `mysql_query`.  How different is the syntax between it and PDO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my suggestion for your query.

First of all, I needed to find out the week number based on the date field so I used the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785206/function-for-week-of-the-month-in-mysql):

```
SELECT  WEEK(dateField, 5) -
        WEEK(DATE_SUB(dateField, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(dateField) - 1 DAY), 5) + 1
```

I'll refer to the the result of the above as @week from now on to make things more readable :)

Then, I started out with just one of the tables, trying to see how many visitors a sales rep got in each month:

```
select rep, 
  , SUM(CASE @week WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Week1
  , SUM(CASE @week WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Week2
  , SUM(CASE @week WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Week3
  , SUM(CASE @week WHEN 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Week4
  , COUNT(*) as Total
from visitors
group by rep
```

Now that we got this info, we'll use the same for buyers and then join the results of these two subqueries as follows:

```
select v.rep
, v.Week1 , b.Week1
, v.Week2 , b.Week2
, v.Week3 , b.Week3
, v.Week4 , b.Week4
, v.Total, b.Total
from (
     select rep, 
        , SUM(CASE @week WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Week1
        , SUM(CASE @week WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Week2
        , SUM(CASE @week WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Week3
        , SUM(CASE @week WHEN 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Week4
        , COUNT(*) as Total
     from visitors
     group by rep) as v
     left join (select rep, 
                 , SUM(CASE @week WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Week1
                 , SUM(CASE @week WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Week2
                 , SUM(CASE @week WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Week3
                 , SUM(CASE @week WHEN 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Week4
                 , COUNT(*) as Total
                from visitors
                group by rep) as b on v.rep = b.rep
```

This should be what you're looking for!

Here's the same code as above updated for your situation:

```
select v.rep
    , v.Week1 , b.Week1
    , v.Week2 , b.Week2
    , v.Week3 , b.Week3
    , v.Week4 , b.Week4
    , v.Total, b.Total
from (
        select rep
          , SUM(CASE WEEK(the_date, 5) -
            WEEK(DATE_SUB(the_date, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(the_date) - 1 DAY), 5) + 1
            WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Week1
      , SUM(CASE WEEK(the_date, 5) -
            WEEK(DATE_SUB(the_date, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(the_date) - 1 DAY), 5) + 1
            WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Week2
      , SUM(CASE WEEK(the_date, 5) -
        WEEK(DATE_SUB(the_date, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(the_date) - 1 DAY), 5) + 1
            WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Week3
      , SUM(CASE WEEK(the_date, 5) -
        WEEK(DATE_SUB(the_date, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(the_date) - 1 DAY), 5) + 1
            WHEN 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Week4
      , COUNT(*) as Total
        from visitors
        where sales_rep = '$sales_rep' AND date('Y-m') = $'chosen_month'
        group by rep ) as v
  left join (
        select rep
          , SUM(CASE WEEK(the_date, 5) -
            WEEK(DATE_SUB(the_date, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(the_date) - 1 DAY), 5) + 1
            WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Week1
      , SUM(CASE WEEK(the_date, 5) -
            WEEK(DATE_SUB(the_date, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(the_date) - 1 DAY), 5) + 1
            WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Week2
      , SUM(CASE WEEK(the_date, 5) -
        WEEK(DATE_SUB(the_date, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(the_date) - 1 DAY), 5) + 1
            WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Week3
      , SUM(CASE WEEK(the_date, 5) -
        WEEK(DATE_SUB(the_date, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(the_date) - 1 DAY), 5) + 1
            WHEN 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Week4
      , COUNT(*) as Total
        from buyers
        where marketing_type = "URL" AND sales_rep = '$sales_rep' AND date('Y-m') = $'chosen_month'
        group by rep) as b on v.rep = b.rep
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The code appears to be working, but I can't get any data to display.  I'm using a while loop to extract the variables from the query, and I'm not receiving any errors from PHP or MySQL.  Should I use a different method to extract the data?

Comment: First of all you should try to run your query directly in sql - use Phpmyadmin or Mysql Workbench for this. Once you're sure the results are as expected, then you should try to use the query in your code.

Comment: Also, I see I used a different name for the date column: "the_date" instead of "date" as you had in your example. And the condition you used "date('Y-m') = $'chosen_month'" will never work, since it doesn't filter by the `date` column - here `date` is a function.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I changed the date to a Date_Format function before comparing it.  After a little clean-up, everything worked perfectly.