# late coming and early going query in mysql with case and if condition

Tags: mysql, case

I am working employee timesheet and below are the tables.
There are two shifts for employees in department `Tech Support` and `Network`
i.e. `[ 8:00 AM to 2:00 PM ]` and `[ 1:00 PM to 7:00 PM ]`

And normal shift `[ 9:00 AM to 6:00 PM ]`

Now, what I am trying to get report of persons coming late and leaving early.
I have few logic on server side code, but its running damn slow. So i wanted to make it from database.

### What I am doing

I am generating a report, employees who are coming late and leaving early

### The Algorithm

1. To find the employee starting time.. with respective to Department.. and respective shifts
2. If employee department is Software, make one time shift else make two time shift with the day
3. From punchin time and logout time.. find the employee shift.
4. If employee shift is under First shift, use intime as `08:00:00 AM` and outtime as `01:00:00 PM`
5. If employee shift is under Second shift, use intime as `02:00:00 PM` and outtime as `07:00:00 PM`
6. If employee shift is under Normal shift, use intime as `08:55:00 AM` and outtime as `06:00:00 PM`

Then find, 
Now find its login_time and log

### Tables

### employees

```
emp_id  |   emp_name    |   emp_dept
--------------------------------------
1       |   Billy J     |   1
2       |   Sarah k     |   2
3       |   Takashi M   |   3
4       |   Matsuzaka   |   2
```

### department

```
dept_id |   dept_name
--------------------------
1       |   Software
2       |   Tech Support
3       |   Network
```

### employee_login

```
emp_id  |   login_time          |   logout_time
----------------------------------------------------------
1       |   2013-02-18 19:10:42 |   2013-02-18 21:27:37
2       |   2013-02-18 19:38:59 |   2013-02-18 22:46:14
3       |   2013-02-18 15:13:53 |   2013-01-01 18:26:39
4       |   2013-01-01 08:41:40 |   2013-01-01 016:41:40
```

### SQL Query, I tried and little incomplete..

```
SELECT e.emp_id, e.emp_name, d.dept_name,
CASE d.dept_name
    WHEN d.dept_name IN ('Software') THEN 
        @intime := '08:55:00 AM'
    ELSE
        @intime := '02:00:00 PM'

END AS `StartingTime`,
@entrytime := DATE_FORMAT(el.login_time, '%r%') AS `Entered into Office`
TIMEDIFF(@entryTime,@intime) `difference`,
IF(TIMEDIFF(@entryTime,@intime)<'00:00:00',NULL,TIMEDIFF(@entryTime,@intime)) AS `Delay`

FROM employees e
INNER JOIN department d ON d.dept_id = e.emp_dept
INNER JOIN employee_login el ON el.emp_id = e.emp_id
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(el.login_time, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2013-06-01' AND '2013-06-26'
ORDER BY el.login_time DESC;
```

Comment: Also in employee_login table 3rd Entry is not proper. Logout time is before login time.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: I don't think that doing it with SQL will be faster (just a guess I don't know your tables size), can you provide the "logic" you used (a shell script?) it can maybe be improved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is the code for this **new** ***simplified*** CASE **[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/785fe/90).** Here is the old CASE **[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/785fe/80)**.
- Some columns are not really needed, and you can eliminate them, if you want.
- **Notice!** that I had to use ***CASE*** in every column that needed to be set according to the conditions about departments. Also, notice that I have used the timings that you put at the begging of your question. If you want to change them, don't forget to do so in every CASE statement, otherwise you would not get the results that you want.

```
SELECT e.emp_id, d.dept_name, e.emp_name,
CASE d.dept_name
    WHEN 'Tech Support' THEN '08:00:00'
    WHEN 'Network' THEN '13:00:00'
    ELSE '09:00:00'
END AS `StartingTime`,
CASE d.dept_name
    WHEN 'Tech Support' THEN '14:00:00'
    WHEN 'Network' THEN '19:00:00'
    ELSE '18:00:00'
END AS `EndingTime`,
TIME_FORMAT(el.login_time, '%T') AS `Entered_into_Office`,
TIME_FORMAT(el.logout_time, '%T') AS `Left_from_Office`,
CASE d.dept_name
    WHEN 'Tech Support' THEN 
        TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(TIME_FORMAT(el.login_time, '%T'), TIME_FORMAT('08:00:00', '%T')), '%T')
    WHEN 'Network' THEN
        TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(TIME_FORMAT(el.login_time, '%T'), TIME_FORMAT('13:00:00', '%T')), '%T')
    ELSE 
        TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(TIME_FORMAT(el.login_time, '%T'), TIME_FORMAT('09:00:00', '%T')), '%T')
END AS `Time_in_diff`,
CASE d.dept_name
    WHEN 'Tech Support' THEN 
        TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(TIME_FORMAT('14:00:00', '%T'), TIME_FORMAT(el.logout_time, '%T')), '%T')
    WHEN 'Network' THEN
        TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(TIME_FORMAT('19:00:00', '%T'), TIME_FORMAT(el.logout_time, '%T')), '%T')
    ELSE
        TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(TIME_FORMAT('18:00:00', '%T'), TIME_FORMAT(el.logout_time, '%T')), '%T')
END AS `Time_out_diff`,
CASE d.dept_name
    WHEN 'Tech Support' THEN TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(
        TIME_TO_SEC(TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(TIME_FORMAT(el.login_time, '%T'), TIME_FORMAT('08:00:00', '%T')), '%T'))
       +TIME_TO_SEC(TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(TIME_FORMAT('14:00:00', '%T'), TIME_FORMAT(el.logout_time, '%T')), '%T'))), '%T')    
    WHEN 'Network' THEN TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(
        TIME_TO_SEC(TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(TIME_FORMAT(el.login_time, '%T'), TIME_FORMAT('13:00:00', '%T')), '%T'))
       +TIME_TO_SEC(TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(TIME_FORMAT('19:00:00', '%T'), TIME_FORMAT(el.logout_time, '%T')), '%T'))), '%T')
    ELSE TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(
        TIME_TO_SEC(TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(TIME_FORMAT(el.login_time, '%T'), TIME_FORMAT('09:00:00', '%T')), '%T'))
       +TIME_TO_SEC(TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(TIME_FORMAT('18:00:00', '%T'), TIME_FORMAT(el.logout_time, '%T')), '%T'))), '%T')    
END AS `Total_time_diff`
FROM employees e
INNER JOIN department d ON d.dept_id = e.emp_dept
INNER JOIN employee_login el ON el.emp_id = e.emp_id
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(el.login_time, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2013-12-31'
HAVING Total_time_diff > 0;
```

***Below are my previous solutions:***
In this **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6113/74)** I have made 4 queries for your scope. This is the query for one department. I didn't use CASE condition, but it works. One for each time-shift and one taking data for all time-sheets. For the later I had to remove this line: `ORDER BY Time_in_diff DESC;`, in order for the **UNION** be successful. Let me know if it helps! 
Here is a **[solution with prepared statements](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6113/103)**.

Comment: Thanks Gimmy, it took 2ms executing this statement.. I am gonna use this.

Comment: Glad to know that. I've just managed to make the SELECT run with variables. I didn't understood the correct syntax, till now. Couldn't make it to work with the last having clause though. Here is the: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/785fe/119  Hope it helps!

Comment: actually i did made small modification into your code and i run the code and its working and implelemented in project successful.

Comment: Got another twist man!, on `2nd` and `5th` of `Saturday`, its HalfDay.. its really going nuts.. Whatever, I am gonna do it.

Comment: Consider the SELECT CASE from this SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/383c0/12 It gives you some CASE options for SATURDAY. Not sure what you can do about the selection of the particular Saturdays in month. There's a possible solution that I put in one CASE for Tech Support. Not sure about it.

Comment: I got that stuff. from other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785206/function-for-week-of-the-month-in-mysql and got the result.. once again. thanks